# Nullpointer Exception in J2MEmicroDb createTable function

Tags: java-me

My code is

```
         J2MESDLIB.generateDB(true);
        J2MEColumn c1 = new J2MEColumn("desc", true, J2MEColumn.ColumnType.VARCHAR, 20);
        J2MEColumn c2=new J2MEColumn("date", false, J2MEColumn.ColumnType.VARCHAR, 20);
        J2MEColumn c3=new J2MEColumn("type", false, J2MEColumn.ColumnType.VARCHAR, 20);
        J2MEColumn c4=new J2MEColumn("assigned", false, J2MEColumn.ColumnType.VARCHAR, 100);

        Vector vector=new Vector(4);
        vector.addElement(c1);
        vector.addElement(c2);
        vector.addElement(c3);
        vector.addElement(c4);

       J2METable table1=J2MESDLIB.createTable("todo", vector, 1);
```

it gives exception at the last line 
i.e java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at edu.upc.J2MESDLIB.J2MEDBException.(J2MEDBException.java:82)
        at edu.upc.J2MESDLIB.J2MESDLIB.createTable(J2MESDLIB.java:193)
        at hello.TodoRecordStore.openRecord(TodoRecordStore.java:52)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I downloaded J2MEMicroDB from the [first result](http://morfeo.upc.es/crom/mod/resource/view.php?id=263) of a [google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=J2MEMicroDB), it only supported one default language for `J2MEDBException` messages.

I assume the version you have would have been localised.

The `NullPointerException` could be caused by a bad language-specific set of error messages.

Unfortunately, that only means the `NullPointerException` is only masking the `J2MEDBException` that J2MEMicroDB was trying to throw.

Given the code you posted, my only guess as to the original `J2MEDBException` would be that the "todo" table already exists.